# How to avoid table duplication in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I don't know much about MySQL, and I'm in the following situation:

- An *Artist* table, with an id and a string
- A *Level* table, with an id and a string
- A *Style* table, with an id and a string

Then, I have 3 tables that are completely identical :

- A *Fill* table, with some custom fields + referencing the 3 tables above
- A *Beat* table, with some custom fields + referencing the 3 tables above
- A *Sheet* table, with some custom fields + referencing the 3 tables above

The only difference between those 3 last tables is that they won't be treated the same way on the front-end part (one category for each kind).

Thus, I was wondering if there's any better solution that just having 3 completly identical tables in MySQL. I thought about doing a *"pivot"* table with 3 boolean columns (is_beat, is_fill and is_sheet that would be mutually exclusive), yet I have no idea if it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and explain the relationship between the tables. And btw Isnt always bad have different tables even when similar if they describe different entities..

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the `Fill`, `Beat`, and `Sheet` tables into a single table by having the same original columns along with a *new* column which will describe what type of category it is.  You could call the column `type`.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    artist_id int,
    level_id int,
    style_id int,
    custom_1 varchar,
    custom_2 varchar,
    ...
    type varchar,    -- can be 'Fill', 'Beat', or 'Sheet'

    FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES Artist (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (level_id)  REFERENCES Level (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (style_id)  REFERENCES Style (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table that defines your "categories" by string and relate the uid/guid of each row in that table to a column in the single table that holds your Fill/Beat/Sheet rows. You could call it 'type' and then hold the guid/uid relating to the category table. This also allows for unlimited "category" types.